# Xlsx Writer not creating excel file but not creating an error either

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

When I run this in python, I get no errors. However, when I check the folder in which I have my program saved, no excel file is created. Not sure what I did wrong.

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("result.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.write('A1','plz work')

workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your IDE or the way you're running your script, the current directory can be anything but not necessarily the directory where the script is located.

To create the file where the script is located, a good trick is this:

```
import os
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),"result.xlsx"))
```

`__file__` is the path of your current script, taking the directory name & joining to file base name creates the absolute path of your output file. I used `os.path.abspath` on it because it can return a basename (depending on how it is run, and as opposed to Unix command `dirname`, `os.path.dirname` of a basename doesn't return `.` but empty string, so the `os.path.join` fails in that case.